# Realloc on an array of structs, address boundary error when indexing

Tags: c, arrays, struct, malloc, realloc

I have some code where I'm trying to read lines in from a file and store some information from each line in a struct.  Since I don't know how long the file will be, I'm dynamically adjusting the array of structs using `realloc`.

My issue is that my code seems to work fine for the first 3 (technically 6) lines, and then I receive SIGSEGV (address boundary error).  `gdb` says that this happens when trying to index the array (`array[i]->string = (char*) _tmp`).

```
typedef struct {
    char* string;
    int len;
} buffer;


int read_into_array(char *filename, buffer** array) {
    int n;
    size_t size;
    char* buf = NULL;
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");

    int i = 0;
    while (1) {
        buffer *tmp = (buffer*)realloc(*array, sizeof(buffer) * (i + 1));
        if (!tmp)
            printf("Failed realloc\n");

        *array = tmp;

        // First line is ignored, second line is taken as data.
        getline(&buf, &size, file);
        n = getline(&buf, &size, file);
        if (n > 0) {
            void* _tmp = malloc(sizeof(char) * n);
            if (!_tmp)
                printf("Failed malloc\n");

            array[i]->string = (char*) _tmp;
            array[i]->len = n-1;
            strncpy(array[i]->string, buf, n-1);
        }

        i++;
        if (feof(file)) {
            printf("saw end of file, leaving.\n");
            break;
        }
    }

    return i;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    char *filename = argv[1];

    buffer *array = (buffer*) calloc(1, sizeof(buffer));
    int num = read_into_array(filename, &array);
}
```

Apologies for the somewhat poor formatting, I've been trying to figure this out for a while.

Since it seems to work for the first few lines, my assumption is that I'm going wrong somewhere in the `realloc` calculation.  My other guess is that I'm somehow using/reading the file incorrectly.

Thanks for any help.  For posterity, the file looks something like this https://hastebin.com/vinidiyita.sm (the real file is thousands of lines long).

Comment: aside `array[i]->string` is not null-terminated.

Comment: Remember that `array` is a *pointer* to an "array". You forget to dereference that pointer.

Comment: On an unrelated note, remember that [`strncpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy) might not terminate the string it copies.

Comment: if the dereferencing was wrong how to explain that `array[i]->string` compiles?

Comment: `buffer *array = (buffer*) calloc(1, sizeof(buffer));` is useless, you're reallocating with the same size in your routine. Better set to `NULL`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Because `array[i]` is a pointer to a structure, where you can access the elements using the `->` operator. You could see `array` (in the function) as an array of pointers to structures, instead of a pointer to an array of structures.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude would you be able to elaborate on where I'm forgetting to dereference?  Why does the program work for the first few items?

Comment: when I see those kinds of problems, I love C++ even more, with references, _strings_ & _vectors_ !

Comment: @Toqoz You have [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) which is some cases might *seem* to work. It makes your whole program *ill-formed* and invalid. The solution is to do e.g. `(*array)[i].string = ...`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude That makes total sense, went right over my head.  Thank you.

Comment: You should *always validate* all input functions, e.g. `if (getline(&buf, &size, file) == -1) { /* handle error or bail */}` and `if ((n = getline(&buf, &size, file)) == -1) { /* handle error or bail */}`. **Note:** this would also replace your use of `if (feof(file))`, which is questionable at best.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin noted, though these differ in the real program.

Answer (score 0):

when you do *array=tmp you're allocating memory for array[0]

then you're using array[i] that should be a pointer to a buffer, but points to garbage or 0

You're confusing two ways to use data.

The first is by using arrays - there's the non-dynamic:

```
buffer array[x] = {0};
int num = read_into_array(filename, &array);
```

then you can use array[i]

and there's the dynamic type:

```
buffer **array = calloc(initial_len*sizeof(buffer *));
int num = read_into_array(filename, array, initial_len);
read_into_array(char *filename, buffer **&array, int initial_len)
{
    int len = initial_len;
...
    while()
    {
        ...
        if(i>len)
        {
            array = realloc(array, sizeof(buffer*) * (i + 1));
            len = i;
        }
        array[i] = calloc(sizeof(buffer));
    }
}
```

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying, but I'm trying to make the array dynamic on both sides -- so no `max_len`.  If this case I think that I have to use `realloc`, and so this solution isn't really viable.
You're right that I wasn't "stepping into" the array, see comments on the original question.

Comment: edited accordingly. buffer **& is required if you want to use it outside read_into_array(), otherwise you can use buffer **